# Accessing both table data through relation Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have to tables with a many-to-many relationship shown below

thought_journal_entries and emotions. The pivot table thought_journal_entry_emotions is also below.

How can I use the data in the pivot table to access data from both tables. For example, `tj_entry_id` 13 is associated with `em_id` 3 & 5 and I want to access the images for these id's in the emotions table. How could I do this within the controller?

[image]

[image]

They are joined by this pivot table

[image]

```
class Emotions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'emotions';
    public $primarykey = 'id';

    public function thoughtJournalEntries() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ThoughtJournalEntry::class, 'thought_journal_entry_emotions',
        'em_id', 'tj_entry_id');
    }

}
```

```
class ThinkingTraps extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'thinking_traps';
    public $primarykey = 'id';

    public function thoughtJournalEntries() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ThoughtJournalEntry::class, 'thought_journal_entry_emotions',
        'tt_id', 'tj_entry_id');
    }
}
```

```
class ThoughtJournalEntry extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'thought_journal_entries';
    public $primarykey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function emotions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Emotions::class, 'thought_journal_entry_emotions',
        'tj_entry_id', 'em_id');
    }

    public function thinkingTraps() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ThinkingTraps::class, 'thought_journal_entry_thinking_traps',
        'tj_entry_id', 'tt_id');
    }

}
```

Here is the controller

```
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $thought_journal_entries = ThoughtJournalEntry::with('emotions')->where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
        /*$thought_journal_entries = \DB::table('thought_journal_entries')->where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);*/

        return view('thoughtjournal.index')->with('thought_journal_entries', $thought_journal_entries);
```

Comment: How are your models set up? Could you share the code please?

Comment: I have just updated my question with models

Answer (score 1):

I believe using the `with`  method should help here, the so-called eager-loading. So in your controller you would do something like this:

```
$thought_journal_entries = ThoughtJournalEntry::with('emotions')
      ->where('id', 13)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

In the view you would do as follows then:

```
@foreach($thought_journal_entries as $entry)
  {{$entry->id}}
  @foreach($entry->emotions as $emotion)
    {{$emotion->id}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Great thanks. Also how would I reference this in the view file?
@foreach($thought_journal_entries as $thought_journal_entry)
@foreach($emotions as $emotion)
{{ $emotion->image }}
@endforeach

Comment: Something like what I just added to the answer

Comment: I think I might be going wrong in the controller, I've just added my code to the question. Appreciate your help

Comment: Just not returning anything 
@foreach($thought_journal_entry->$emotions as $emotion)
           <p>{{ $emotion->image }}</p>
 @endforeach

Comment: Displaying your image blob data is a different thing... You should google for that. check if the looping works with displaying the IDs

Comment: Yes this needs to be added to the controller:

foreach($thought_journal_entries as $thought_journal_entry) {
            foreach($thought_journal_entry->$emotions as $emotion) {
                $emotion->image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $emotion->image);
            }
        }

I'm not sure its correct though as error is still being returned